# How to configure Hive libraries in Maven - POM.XML

Tags: datastax-enterprise

We would like to run automated Hive jobs (short running ones) thru Maven/JUnit. Reviewed details at site: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive. But could not find the specific configuration that should be used in Maven pom.xml to use Hive libraries. Appreciate suggestions for this configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to create junit test for hive.
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/ENSVdtuZmIA

But to test DSE hive, you need find a way to start an embedded DSE server as a hadoop node and  hive client setting when you setup a test case. DSE is close source, so I am not sure when we will disclose how to start an embedded DSE server and set hive client